# How can I prevent part of a class's package name from being obfuscated with ProGuard (or R8)?

Tags: proguard, android-r8

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
com.example.whatever.ClassA
com.example.whatever.ClassB
```

I want to obfuscate my class and package names, but keep the `com.example` prefix. Obfuscating the above names with this in mind should output something like:

```
com.example.a.a
com.example.a.b
```

There's the `-keeppackagenames` flag, but I don't want to keep the whole package name - just the prefix.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Any updates on that one? We were using `-keeppackagenames com.example` with the Proguard... It was working pretty fine. Now we are trying to migrate fully to R8 and that keep rule does not work... and that causes issues.